# Which one is created first? Database or Instance?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, instance

The Oracle database includes all the physical files belonging to the server while the Oracle instance will provide the interface between the user and the data he wants to manipulate. But I want to know which one is created first?

I had thought the database should be created first, before the instance. But after I read this post [Creating a Database with the CREATE DATABASE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/create.htm#ADMIN11073) I think I am.

Because the manual shows theses instructions:

Step 5: (Windows Only) Create an Instance 
Step 9: Issue the `CREATE DATABASE` statement

Answer (score 4):

[Introduction to the Oracle Database Instance](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT601)

> A database instance is a set of memory structures that manage database
> files. A database is a set of physical files on disk created by the
> CREATE DATABASE statement. The instance manages its associated data
> and serves the users of the database.
>
> Every running Oracle database is associated with at least one Oracle
> database instance. Because an instance exists in memory and a database
> exists on disk, an instance can exist without a database and a
> database can exist without an instance.

A database can exist without an instance, but to use that database, you need to start an instance, then mount and open the database in it.

You can "create" a database by simply copying the files of an existing database. You do not need an instance for that. But to use that database, you need an instance.

If you want to create a database from scratch, you need a running instance first.

Answer (score 0):

Instance can not be created, it can "only" be started. Instance is something which is running.

oradim is something Windows specific. It creates a record in Windows SERVICE registry, to start the instance during the boot. So in fact oradim does not create an instance, it creates a Windows service associated with the database (instance).

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, Instance is created first. Because when you create database manually, you start the instance first in no mount state and run the script for creating database. Another point to support my answer, access to Oracle database or creation of it is impossible without an instance.